# UIStatusBarAnimationFade duration

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uistatusbar

I have an app where I have a button that fades the screen to black. I want to have the status bar fade to black also, so I'm using the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

Is it possible for me to set the duration of the fade? If that's not doable, is it possible to get the official fade duration (like using `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` to get the keyboard slide duration).

---

Well I didn't get anything back from anyone, but I think I should at least share my hack. After some experimentation, I settled on fade out is 1 second and fade in is 0.25 seconds.

```
- (IBAction)fadeToBlack:(id)sender
{
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.window.frame] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    view.alpha = 0.0;
    [self.view.window addSubview:view];

    // NOTE: Fading the black view at the same rate as the status bar. Duration is just a guess.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        view.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [view addGestureRecognizer:self.dismissViewGesture];
    }];
}

- (void)dismissViewWithGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIView *view = gesture.view;
    [view removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];

    // NOTE: Fading the black view at the same rate as the status bar. Duration is just a guess.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        view.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my values are 0.5 for hiding and 0.2 for showing the navigation bar together with the status bar. 
At least for iOS 6.1/iOS Simulator those values are matching the reality much better.